# Python Tkinter Spinbox with float

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to get a float value (like 1.91, 1.92 and so on) using the tkinter Spinbox Widget in Python 3.x?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `format` and the `increment` options. Format takes a string format value; use something like `%.2f` for a floating point number truncated to two decimal places.

The increment option specifies the increment value; the default is 1.0.

Now, using `get()` on a Spinbox returns an instance of `str`. Typecast it to float to get a floating-point value.

Comment: Thank you very much, for everyone who needs an example: Spinbox(root,format="%.2f",increment=0.01) is what I needed.